# modprobe: FATAL: Module lirc_rpi not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.92-v7+

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, gpio, lirc

I am trying to Configure Lirc for my Rpi 3b+ for a personal project. I am using [this guide](https://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/03/Controlling-your-Pi-with-an-infrared-remote/(offset)/2). When running `sudo modprobe lirc_rpi`I get the error of `modprobe: FATAL: Module lirc_rpi not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.92-v7+` Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

That LIRC should not work on Rpi is a misunderstanding. LIRC works on all linux systems, RPi included, but certainly not on Arduino (Arduino don't run Linux).

The basic problem is that the guide you refer to is severely outdated. In particular, the hardware.conf file is not used on modern LIRC installations.

As for the possible need for a lirc_rpi kernel moduled this depends on the actual use case. In most cases, LIRC uses either the serial ports or the lirc0 device, neither of which needing any specific kernel module.

The complete upstream docs are available at https://www.lirc.org/html/configuration-guide.html. It might be possible to give some more feedback if you describe your use case in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Lirc is not meant to work on raspberry pi, only other computers. You should use something else like an ardino. Good luck